# visual studio foobar2000 component build errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdk

I've been following a development tutorial for foobar2000 components, but keep getting build errors with only minimal code. My VS solution includes these projects from the foobar2000 SDK: foobar2000_component_client, foobar200_SDK, and pfc.

foo_playlists_tag.cpp:

```
#include "U:\SDK\Foobar2000-music-player\foobar2000\SDK\foobar2000.h"
DECLARE_COMPONENT_VERSION("Playlists tagger","0.0.1","About text here");
VALIDATE_COMPONENT_FILENAME("foo_playlists_tag.dll");
```

Build ouput:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: foo_playlists_tag, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  foo_playlists_tag.cpp
1>u:\sdk\foobar2000-music-player\foobar2000\shared\fb2kdebug.h(80): warning C4838: conversion from 'int' to 'const ULONG_PTR' requires a narrowing conversion
1>foo_playlists_tag.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl pfc::myassert_win32(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,unsigned int)" (?myassert_win32@pfc@@YAXPEB_W0I@Z) referenced in function __catch$??$service_add_ref_safe@Vcomponent_installation_validator@@@@YAXPEAVcomponent_installation_validator@@@Z$0
1>foo_playlists_tag.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "char const * __cdecl core_api::get_my_file_name(void)" (?get_my_file_name@core_api@@YAPEBDXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl `anonymous namespace'::componentversion_myimpl::get_file_name(class pfc::string_base &)" (?get_file_name@componentversion_myimpl@?A0xa2c48e39@@UEAAXAEAVstring_base@pfc@@@Z)
1>foo_playlists_tag.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl core_api::are_services_available(void)" (?are_services_available@core_api@@YA_NXZ) referenced in function "protected: __cdecl service_factory_base::service_factory_base(struct _GUID const &,class service_factory_base * &)" (??0service_factory_base@@IEAA@AEBU_GUID@@AEAPEAV0@@Z)
1>foo_playlists_tag.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static bool __cdecl component_installation_validator::test_my_name(char const *)" (?test_my_name@component_installation_validator@@SA_NPEBD@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual bool __cdecl component_installation_validator_filename::is_installed_correctly(void)" (?is_installed_correctly@component_installation_validator_filename@@UEAA_NXZ)
1>foo_playlists_tag.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class service_factory_base * service_factory_base::__internal__list" (?__internal__list@service_factory_base@@2PEAV1@EA)
1>foo_playlists_tag.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct _GUID const componentversion::class_guid" (?class_guid@componentversion@@2U_GUID@@B)
1>foo_playlists_tag.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct _GUID const component_installation_validator::class_guid" (?class_guid@component_installation_validator@@2U_GUID@@B)
1>U:\Repositories\foo_playlists_tag\x64\Debug\foo_playlists_tag.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 7 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 3 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

**Where are these errors coming from? and how can I resovle them?**

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Everything relevant to the question should be in the question. Linking to offsite code renders the question useless once the external host shuffles its links. But before you post the millions of lines of code you might have at that link, please  attempt to fashion it into a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for your constructive criticism

Comment: You weren't kidding about minimal. Two lines. Definitely apologize for the snarky millions of lines comment. What you have there are mostly linker errors. Make sure you've added all of the library to Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker-> Input and provided any necessary paths.

Comment: I've added 'shared.lib' to Linker > Input specified by the readme, but the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer on [hydrogenaud.io](http://hydrogenaud.io) by user kode54:

> In Visual Studio 2010, you must add all dependencies directly to the project you are trying to link, as references. You may find the references list in the Properties dialog for the project, under Common Properties, Frameworks and References. The old style Dependencies dialog doesn't seem to function for that purpose past Visual Studio 2008.

Thank you for your assistance; helped me find that lib file.